# how to change the color which appear "end of scroll" in scroll views and list views

Tags: android, android-layout

i want change this blue color.this color appear when we drag the scroll view.i don't even know android item name of this color.

[image]

```
<item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">
```

this does'not solve my problem.this requires api level 21 or above.but in this scenario my  minSdkVersion is 14.

Comment: `android:colorEdgeEffect` - In style.xml. [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342957/how-to-change-the-color-of-overscroll-edge-and-overscroll-glow)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android lollipop scrollview edge effect color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104521/android-lollipop-scrollview-edge-effect-color)

Comment: there is nothing special.i want change that color which appear end of scroll.i don't know name of that item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This color is the colorEdgeEffect of your theme, you can change that by creating your own theme and assigning to `colorEdgeEffect` like so.

colors.xml file

`<color name="colorEdgeEffect">#FF4081</color>`

styles.xml file

```
<style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorEdgeEffect">@color/colorEdgeEffect</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is wrong, its not the `colorAccent` and instead it is the `colorEdgeEffect`. Do you have any docs to support your claim?

Comment: @Skynet Nope, ill correct my answer immediately, but colorEdgeEffect takes from colorAccent so I just took the easy way out

Comment: colorAccent != colorEdgeEffect

Comment: @Skynet yes I just corrected my answer thanks for the input !

Comment: colorEdgeEffect requires api level 21 or above

Comment: @LahiruPrasanna take a look at this answer for pre lolipop http://stackoverflow.com/a/29469396/4128945